# Change background color of ColumnHeaderStyle based on selection in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

I figured out how to highlight the row of interest.  I can get the index of the column I am interested in and use ScrollIntoView in order to jump to it.  However, it doesn't immediately pop out to the user.  I'd like to highlight the column, or change the ColumnHeaderStyle.  I can't seem to figure out how to do it in the xaml or code behind.

The other alternative is to not highlight the entire row, and column header, but just the cell of interest.  I'd rather do that, but couldn't figure that out.

My current DataGrid looks like this:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="dtGridReads"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"                                       
            VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode ="Standard" 
              EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
              EnableRowVirtualization="True"
            ScrollViewer.IsDeferredScrollingEnabled="True"
            CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" CanUserSortColumns="True"
             ItemsSource ="{Binding}" Block.TextAlignment="Center"
             AlternatingRowBackground="#F1F1F1" RowBackground="White"
              CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" FrozenColumnCount="1"
               GridLinesVisibility="None"                   ScrollViewer.ScrollChanged="dtGridReads_ScrollChanged">

    <DataGrid.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridCell}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="DataGridCell.IsSelected" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="red" />
                    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </DataGrid.CellStyle>
```

My code behind:

```
    public void ShowSelectedCell(int row, int column)
    {
        //dtGridReads.SelectedItem = dtGridReads.Items[row];
        //dtGridReads.SelectedItem = dtGridReads.Columns[column];
        //dtGridReads.CurrentColumn = dtGridReads.Columns[column];
        dtGridReads.ScrollIntoView(dtGridReads.Items[row], dtGridReads.Columns[column]);

    }
```

thanks.

Comment: Changing the `Background` for `DataGridColumnHeader` is pretty much work since you'll need to re-build the style. Not sure if this is what you want but have you tried to set `SelectionUnit="CellOrRowHeader"` on the `DataGrid`?

Comment: @Meleak, what trigger would I use for column selected?

Comment: Not sure I understood your question correctly but I posted an answer on how you could use a trigger for when a `DataGridColumn` is selected (meaning that a cell in the column is selected)

Comment: Then I don't understand your question at all. Your title says change `ColumnHeaderStyle` based on selection in the `DataGrid` and my answer showed exactly that. Maybe upload a picture showing what you want to do. Do you want to make a "red cross" with the cell you are scrolling to in the center?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you need to highlight the data gid column header based on a selected \ highlighted cell ....

Create a `DataGrid` scoped Style for `DataGridColumnHeader`. In the style include a data trigger that checks if the content of the column header and the content of the current cell's column's header are equal ... which means the column header belongs to the column which the current cell also belongs to. If so we change the background color of the header.

```
<toolkit:DataGrid x:Name="MyDataGrid"
      IsReadOnly="True"
      AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>
    <local:EqualityConverter x:Key="EqualityConverter"/>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type toolkit:DataGridColumnHeader}">
      <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True">
          <DataTrigger.Binding>
            <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource EqualityConverter}">
               <Binding Path="CurrentCell.Column.Header"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource
                     AncestorType={x:Type toolkit:DataGrid}}"/>
                <Binding Path="Content"
                  RelativeSource="{RelativeSource Self}"/>
            </MultiBinding>
          </DataTrigger.Binding>
          <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </DataTrigger>
      </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
  </toolkit:DataGrid.Resources>
  <toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Key"
           Binding="{Binding Key, Mode=OneWay}"></toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
    <toolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Value"
           Binding="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"></toolkit:DataGridTextColumn>
  </toolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
</toolkit:DataGrid>
```

`EqualityConverter` is just a multi binding converter that checks if the bound values are equal...

```
public class EqualityConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(
            object[] values,
            Type targetType,
            object parameter,
            System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values != null)
        {
            for (var i = 1; i < values.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (values[i] == null || !values[i].Equals(values[i-1]))
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(
             object value,
             Type[] targetTypes,
             object parameter,
             System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Let me know if that helps.